# Поиск и замена в div который подгружает информацию с помощью post

Tags: jquery, post, replace

Прошу наставить на путь истинный! )

Имеется DIV, который забирает инфу с другой страницы и подгружает ее на основную.

```
$.post(
   'some_page.php', // адрес обработчика
   $("#form").serialize(), // отправляемые данные          
   function(msg) { // получен ответ
      $('#content').html(msg); //тот самый div
   }
);
```

мне нужно найти в `#content` все элементы c классом `.two-side` и заменить их на класс `.one-side`

имею строку замены

```
$('[class*=two-side]').removeClass('two-side').addClass('one-side');
```

а как это все соединить, чет не могу понять ((

не пинайте, я только учусь )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется так:

```
$('.two-side', '#content').removeClass('two-side').addClass('one-side');
```

*а как это все соединить, чет не могу понять ((*

Добавьте код выше, после ставки вашего контента, после

```
$('#content').html(msg);
```